What Is This Fastener And How Is It Used?
The following fastener fell out of a breakfast bar stool.
It came loose from the area shown below, where the hole is.
I have never seen a bolt like that, and Google Lens is not much help-- what is it?
And can this stool be easily repaired?
Note:  I am helping an elderly, internet challenged relative troubleshoot this remotely.  I can ask questions and ask for more pictures (within reason, given limitations on mobility), but I can't put my own hands or eyes on it directly until Christmas, when I will be physically present.  It is at that time I hope to fix it.  If I can figure out how, and what I might need to bring with me.




When assembling chairs like this I usually add glue and/or thread lock. Doing so will make it difficult or impossible to disassemble in the future but usually that's what I want.

Consider the threaded part the same as a "heat-press insert for 3D prints" but for wood, and uses four tangs not heat.

The male threaded part is a bolt or machine screw, and the thing with teeth is a T-nut, which has teeth that hold it against turning in the wood while providing female metal threads in the hole in the wood that it fits into.
As already noted in a comment, the picture of them assembled is assembled backwards - the teeth point towards the head of the screw so that the tightening of the screw drives and/or holds the teeth of the T-nut into the wood. Thus, it goes into the side of the wood away from where the head of the screw is. There should be significant holes in the wood for the teeth there, since it has been assembled before.
You might need to take the seat off to gain access to where the T-nut fits, but the fact that it fell out suggests that the seat is not firmly held against it, so you may be able to simply push the bottom of the seat away from the wood and slip the nut into place, teeth towards wood. In that case the only tool you need is a hex or Allen key the correct size for the screw. A few drops from a container of threadlocker might prevent it from unscrewing again, since the lockwasher clearly didn't.

I can't in good conscience accept this until I try it out near Christmas, but I have upvoted and will remember to revisit after I try the fix.  This does seem likely to work, though.

You can easily unaccept if you find out differently later. It's pretty obvious that this is correct.

Aren't the other legs correctly fastened where you can verify the installation?

While what's described here is the correct way to use a T-nut, I've seen t-nuts used in consumer products oriented as shown in the question, with the bolt being screwed in such that it's pulling the t-nut out of the wood, after the t-nut is hammered/pressed into the wood. In such case, the t-nut is held in place only by the friction of the teeth and barrel being pulled out of the wood. This is vastly less secure and will often result in the t-nut falling out over time, but not prior to the warranty on the product expiring. Given the t-nut fell out, that's not unlikely to be the case here.

I have no earthly idea how only one of those bolts fell out of an otherwise still tight assembly, but somehow it did.  And by some miracle, my hands managed to get it fitted back in without disassembling the whole thing.  Thank you kindly for your help.

To me your middle photo looks like a properly assembled leveler meant for the bottom of furniture legs, and the last photo looks like someone tried to used it in a spot it wasn't designed for.  Search for "furniture leveler" for common examples.


Rather blatantly not. It's a steel screw head with only a hex recess on the bottom - it would scratch up your floor, and you'd have to pick the entire thing up to get a wrench into it. The leveling foot has a non-marring surface and an exposed hex for using an open-end wrench on without picking up what it's attached to.  Looks vaguely similar, but not at all the same. You also appear to have borrowed an image from somewhere without attribution, which is against site policy.

Likewise the washer and lockwash that are clearly visible in the question have nothing to do in this application.
